# Better initialization

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, initialization

I am making an API call to AWS to get a list of AMIs using the Golang SDK. The [`DescribeImages`](http://godoc.org/github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-go/service/ec2#EC2.DescribeImages) function takes in [`DescribeImagesInput`](http://godoc.org/github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-go/service/ec2#DescribeImagesInput). I only want to see my own AMIs, so my code is doing this:

```
// Build input
self := "self"
ownerSelf := []*string{&self}
ownImages := &ec2.DescribeImagesInput{
    Owners: ownerSelf,
}

// Call the DescribeImages Operation
resp, err := svc.DescribeImages(ownImages)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Building input like that is very ugly. I am sure there is a better technique, but being a Golang n00b, I don't know it. What is a better way to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get it any shorter than this:

```
self := "self"
ownImages := &ec2.DescribeImagesInput{Owners: []*string{&self}}
```

Or in one line (without the `self` string variable):

```
ownImages := &ec2.DescribeImagesInput{Owners: []*string{&[]string{"self"}[0]}}
```

(What happens here is I create a `[]string` slice with one element `"self"`, index its only element and take its address and use this value to initialize the required `[]*string`.)

What you can do is create a helper function which constructs the slice of `string` pointers for you:

```
func sp(es ...string) []*string {
    s := make([]*string, len(es))
    for i := range es {
        s[i] = &es[i]
    }
    return s
}
```

With this, the delcaration becomes:

```
ownImages = &ec2.DescribeImagesInput{Owners: sp("self")}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/mJUe5WhV-W).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much more acceptable this is, but it should do the same:

```
self := "self"
resp, err := svc.DescribeImages(
    &ec2.DescribeImagesInput{
        Owners: []*string{&self},
    },
}
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Which could of course be shortened, albeit at the cost of readability IMO

```
self := "self"
resp, err := svc.DescribeImages(&ec2.DescribeImagesInput{Owners:[]*string{&self}}}
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```